# Oracle Error-ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I cannot figure out why I am getting this error message....

```
SELECT student.student, course.coursename, course.coursehours, section.day, section.starttime, course.building, location.room

FROM student, course, section, location, registration

WHERE course.courseid = section.courseid, location.locationid = 
section.locationid, student.studentid = registration.sectionid, 
section.sectionid = registration.sectionid;

Error at line 3:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

I updated my data to look like this:

```
SELECT student.studentid, 
   course.coursename, 
   course.credithours, 
   section.days, 
   section.starttime, 
   location.building, 
   location.room 
FROM   student 
       INNER JOIN registration 
               ON student.studentid = registration.sectionid 
       INNER JOIN section 
               ON section.sectionid = registration.sectionid 
       INNER JOIN location 
               ON location.locationid = section.locationid 
       INNER JOIN course 
               ON course.courseid = section.courseid;
```

but now it is saying "no rows selected"?

Comment: What's the error message? Is this MySQL, SQLite, PostgreSQL?

Comment: @Prdp it wasn't tagged with Oracle when I made the comment.

Comment: What have you tried to debug?  You're joining 5 tables now.  Join 2 tables.  If you get the data you expect, add another.  Build it up testing at each step.  Don't write an entire query and then test it.  If you do that, I suspect that you'll discover that the join from `student` to `registration` is wrong.  I doubt a `studentid` matches a `sectionid`.  I'd guess that there is a `studentid` in `registration` that you intended to join to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have more than one condition you need to use `AND/OR` operator to apply the condition not `comma`. Also start using `INNER JOIN` syntax

```
SELECT student.student, 
       course.coursename, 
       course.coursehours, 
       section.day, 
       section.starttime, 
       course.building, 
       location.room 
FROM   student 
       INNER JOIN registration 
               ON student.studentid = registration.sectionid 
       INNER JOIN section 
               ON section.sectionid = registration.sectionid 
       INNER JOIN location 
               ON location.locationid = section.locationid 
       INNER JOIN course 
               ON course.courseid = section.courseid
```

Comment: Ah, I see.Thanks @Prdp! Is this the newer syntax? I was taught the '92 version above and thought I could still do it the same way...

Comment: I am no longer getting an error message but it is now returning "no rows selected", do you know why this might be?

Comment: @ecooper10 - Without looking at the data it hard to tell. Make sure all the Join conditions are correct and all the tables should have atleast one matching record